# Send the contents of  Android ArrayList to PHP

Tags: php, android, arraylist

I am working as a PHP developer (intermediate level) and do practice some android stuff at home.

I have created and array list which will fetch into an sqlite db inside my Android app and populate a ListView. Now I am trying to take that one level further.

I want to send that array list content to my PHP server where I can store the data given into mysql and fetch back to my app.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of JSON or XML for sending data from android to php server. 
On the PHP side, all you need is the built-in json_decode, which will deserialize your json and return an object or an associative array.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. I find that either the JSON or XML support included in the Android OS is pretty good; either will work well for you and allow communication. Just keep in mind that you will need to get permission to access the network operations in your ApplicationManifest.xml and you will need to send the JSON or XML via the default http object.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to post your data on php server, then fetch that data and store into your database .

Here i attach one example which send data on server and getting response in json .

```
                    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("Your Url");
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


                    // test is a one array list

                    for(int i=0;i<test.size();i++)
                    {
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sample[]", Integer.toString(test.get(i))));
                    }

                    postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
                    // to worry about connection release

                    if (entity != null) 
                    {
                        InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
                        result= convertStreamToString(inStream);
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                        responseHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Here sample[] is a field in which i assign array value to send on server . From server side you have to fetch the sample[] field .

---

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   String line = null;
   try 
   {
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } 
   finally 
   {
       try 
       {
           is.close();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return sb.toString();
```

}

Comment: i had multiple arraylist then how can i had this all value in List<namepairvalue> ?