# Android : Array in a php POST

Tags: android, arrays, http-post

I'm doing an app that interacts with a mysql database with some php scripts. I would like to know if it is possible to send and array in a php POST from an android activity ?

This is th code I'm using for the moment :

```
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", String.valueOf(userID)));
```

but I think sending and array would be much better than sending one ID at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generate a JSON/XML document. You can easily generate especially JSON objects in Android platform.

There are many examples about [generating JSON in Android](http://localtone.blogspot.com/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html) and [reading/parsing JSON in PHP](http://webhole.net/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a part of the solution in here :

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281107/send-the-contents-of-android-arraylist-to-php)

In his example he simply does a for loop like this :

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            //friendID is an array of friends ID   
    for (int i=0;i<friendID.length;i++){
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAsked[]", String.valueOf(friendID[i])));

    }
```

The thing is : how do I use it in my php file ? Is it as simple as that :

```
$asked[] = $_POST['userAsked[]'];
```

Seems a little bit too easy :s

Comment: I think, It is not ideal way. I recommend you to follow a standart way whatever you do. It will be easier to maintenance your code when you need to.

Comment: What is the standard way :p would that :   for (int i=0;i<friendID.length;i++){
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAsked["+i+"]", String.valueOf(friendID[i])));   
  } be good :p ?

Comment: Standard way to pass data between platforms or via internet is to use XML/JSON in my opinion, if you really curious about.